# Статусы в discord-py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Как зделать кастомный статус в discord-py? В документации я нашел атрибут CustomActivity для активности, и поидеи он должен работать как кастомный статус,   но так и не работает,вот код:

```
await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.CustomActivity(sttstxtf))
```

Если вместо CustomActivity подставить Game то все работает
А ещё хотелось бы узнать как сделать: бот слушает, и бот смотрит

Answer (score 1):

```
        await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Activity(name = f'текст', type = discord.ActivityType.playing)) #Идёт инфа о команде помощи 
        await asyncio.sleep(99)
        await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.idle, activity = discord.Activity(name = f'за {len(bot.guilds)} серверами', type = discord.ActivityType.watching)) #Инфа о количестве серверов, на котором находится бот.
        await asyncio.sleep(99)
        members = 0
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                members += 1
        await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.idle, activity = discord.Activity(name = f'за {members} участниками', type = discord.ActivityType.watching)) #Общее количество участников, за которыми следит бот (Находятся на серверах)
        await asyncio.sleep(99)
```

Статус: (online - онлайн) (idle - отошёл) (dnd - не беспокоить)

Answer (score 0):

Вот самы простой способ как реализовать кастомный статус у своего бота, сам атк сделал своему боту:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)
```

Просто вставьте данный код после импорта модулей, а также `discord.Status.online` можно менятьь на свой статус. `discord.Status.online` - онлайн, `discord.Status.idle` - отошёл и `discord.Status.online` - не беспокоить. И ещё, если у вас перменная в которой создаёться сам бот, вот такая: `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)`, называеться не bot, то замените в коде `@bot.event`, `bot` на название своей переменной

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? Я имел ввиду самый простой статус, без играет, смотрит, слушает, просто чисто статус...

Comment: ```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle)
```

Comment: А оно текст потдерживает?

Comment: Нет, это же иконка . А если вы про описание профиля бота то это можно делать на самой платформе delevopers в discord если я не ошибаюсь. Тоесть через код можно кастомным делать только статуст типо всети лии нет и статус слушает, смотрит, играет и стримит, а описание профился это discord developers. Надеюсь всё правильно объяснил